Wondering why my post directly related to the Thread was deleted?
I originally added my questions to an exiting post that was talking about this EXACT scenario but an admin deleted it EVEN THOUGH my questions was 100% related to the original topic.
I am trying to do a similar thing to this post Bold txtcontent text and not the sharepoint field? with some existing JSON code for a SharePoint list Header using the "Configure Layout" but can't seem to splice in the correct syntax.
How to Bold txtcontent text and not the sharepoint field?

KRP
That's the thing. This is an Q-n-A only and not a forum. We don't add new questions to existing ones. This is not a forum.
So head over to the tour, and ask again if you have more questions!

Still confused, I read the entire "tour" link and I don't see anything that points out an issue with my post.
I was having the same issue and tried the provided suggested solution and it wasn't working so I had questions about it.
If I must create a brand new post to ask the original person who provided the solution, I guess I'll have to hope he actually finds my question then remembers his original answer so they can then hopefully comment or clarify?

@SA-KRP It's not allowed to "added my questions to an exiting post". Those fields are only for answers. To ask a question, you need to create a new post.
